# How to write the data of framebuffer to PBO

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to write the data from current framebuffer to PBO.

I have been reading through various examples on the Internet and this is what i assume the process should be.

```
 // Read from the Front framebuffer
  glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT); 


// read pixels from framebuffer to PBO
  glGenBuffers(1, &pbo);
  glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo);
  glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, width*height*4, NULL, GL_STREAM_COPY);
 glReadPixels(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

 // get the data from PBO
 glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo);
  void* mappedBuffer = glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);
```

Now i can use the mappedBuffer pointer to access the data ?

Comment: I can't see any obvious issue in this code.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Once i have the mappedBuffer pointer can i update a GL_TEXTURE_2D with this pointer.

Comment: glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_BGRA, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mappedBuffer);

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes i did but screen appears black.

Comment: i think i should post my code as a separate question.